# How to use django-taggit similar_objects() with Class-based views

Tags: django, django-taggit

I want to display 4 related item on my template which have the same tags as the current item.
I'm using the greate package django-taggit and I have read django-taggit [doc](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

and they didn't explain how to use "similar_objects() " to make related item with Class-based views

my views.py:

```
class GameDetail(DetailView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'core/game_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'game_detail'
```

my models.py :

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    game_trailer = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="No Trailer")
    game_story = models.TextField(default='No Story')
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

my template "game_detail.html" is very long to post it here if you just can explain how to use django-taggit in my view and how to display the related item on template I'll be grateful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build your view this way:

```
class GameDetail(DetailView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'core/game_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'game_detail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["related_items"] = self.object.tags.similar_objects()[:4]
        return context
```

Then you can use the `related_items` list on your template, like you normally do.

**Note:** if you are using `python2` the `super` call should be this one:

```
context = super(self, GameDetail).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, it give me this error  `'Game' object has no attribute 'similar_objects' `

Comment: i found the problem it should be `self.object.tags.similar_objects()[:4]` not `self.object.similar_objects()[:4]` please update your answer so i can accept it

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to add the field, fixed.